# What should I use: his or their

Tags: word-choice

Should I use HIS or THEIR in the sentence:

> Which of the students of your group does __________ homework together?

Comment: The only way it could be *his* with a single person and *together* is if he has multiple personalities …

Answer (score 3):

"Their" because the subject is "which". "Which" can be *either* singular or plural, but in this case it is definitely to be understood as plural because of the word "together". Doing homework *together* certainly implies more than one participant.

The verb in the sentence should also be plural, "do". So the correct sentence should be:

> Which of the students of your group do their  homework together?

Answer (score -2):

Their. Because it is about "the students". It is from meaning of this sentence.

From other hand, if you put "his" in this place in sentence, this would be depend on more wide context. But for this sentence, without anything else - more logical choice is "their".

Comment: The [answer by Lorel C.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/230507) is much better. Consider this question: _Which of the students in your group left **his** gloves on the table?_ We do not need to use _their_ instead of _his_ in that sentence.

Comment: Don't agree with you. Because, more wide context of your example can be about some specific situation, when this "his" have a important meaning.

Comment: I was trying to teach you some tips for helping you better understand English, since clearly you could use the help. But if you want to cling to your mistaken beliefs, well, that's your call.

Comment: This is right, but when you say "his", this is about male student only? This is about more wide context, isn't?

Comment: Correct, to use "his" context would indicate this must be a male student. (Perhaps we are in an all-male school, or perhaps the gloves clearly belong to a man.) If you want to say that _their_ is a good choice when you don't know the gender of the person (a.k.a. "singular they"), that would be a legitimate argument. However, your answer doesn't mention gender or singular they.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Sentence: "Which of the students of your group does his homework together?" I think can be used, when it is about homework of the student of this group who can't do his homework himself, and some of the other students do it together to help him. I understand this is synthetic context, but question is - can be form of sentence with "his" is right in some contexts?

Comment: No, for the reasons explained in the other answer.

Comment: @sayfriend abt the (hypothetical) sentence, "Which of the students of your group does his homework *before supper*?": would be OK. It could be about *one* student of the group. Even: (hypothetically)  "Which of the students of your group does his homework together *with a friend*?" could be singular (one student). but "Which of the students of your group do *their* homework *together*?". Here we must be discussing a plural subject because "together" (not introducing who *else* is included in "together") implies "together [*within* a group]"... necessarily plural. Hope it's not *more* confusing

Comment: Thank you, Lorel C. Really clear explanation for me!